# Load data from json in tabulator?

Tags: javascript, json, tabulator

I have this json variable and want to draw table by tabulator:

```
mydata=
[
  {
    "trade_symbol": "Media",
    "technical_sum_List": [
      19,
      5,
      4
    ],
    "volume_sum_List": [
      6,
      1
    ],
    "pivot_sum_list": [
      5,
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "trade_symbol": "Sport",
    "technical_sum_List": [
      18,
      4,
      4
    ],
    "volume_sum_List": [
      3,
      4
    ],
    "pivot_sum_list": [
      5,
      0,
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "trade_symbol": "Dance",
    "technical_sum_List": [
      13,
      10,
      5
    ],
    "volume_sum_List": [
      1,
      6
    ],
    "pivot_sum_list": [
      2,
      2,
      0
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to insert technical_sum_List[1] or technical_sum_List[2] in each columns by tabulator.
in tabulator we can only use field:"technical_sum_List" and do not accept technical_sum_List[1]!

Answer (score 1):

There might be an easier way but you can do this through using a [customFormatter](http://www.tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#format-custom). The gist is that when you define your table columns, you add a `formatterParam` which tells Tabulator which index in the array to reference and the name of the custom formatter function. Defining a separate function means you can reuse it for all your arrays.

```
{title:"B-1", field:"technical_sum_List", formatterParams: {index:0}, formatter: customFormatter},
```

---

Get the cell value and then use the formatterParams to reference and return the data at that array position.

```
function customFormatter(cell, formatterParams) {
   return cell.getValue()[formatterParams.index];
}
```

```js
let myData = [{
  "trade_symbol": "Media",
  "technical_sum_List": [
   19,
   5,
   4
  ],
  "volume_sum_List": [
   6,
   1
  ],
  "pivot_sum_list": [
   5,
   0,
   0
  ]
 },
 {
  "trade_symbol": "Sport",
  "technical_sum_List": [
   18,
   4,
   4
  ],
  "volume_sum_List": [
   3,
   4
  ],
  "pivot_sum_list": [
   5,
   0,
   0
  ]
 },
 {
  "trade_symbol": "Dance",
  "technical_sum_List": [
   13,
   10,
   5
  ],
  "volume_sum_List": [
   1,
   6
  ],
  "pivot_sum_list": [
   2,
   2,
   0
  ]
 }
]

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    columns:[
    {title:"A", field:"trade_symbol"},
    {title:"B-1", field:"technical_sum_List", 
    formatterParams: {index:0},
    formatter: customFormatter},
    
     {title:"B-2", field:"technical_sum_List", 
    formatterParams: {index:1},
    formatter: customFormatter},
    
     {title:"B-3", field:"technical_sum_List", 
    formatterParams: {index:2},
    formatter: customFormatter},
    
    ],
});

function customFormatter(cell, formatterParams) {
   return cell.getValue()[formatterParams.index];
}


table.setData(myData);
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@spring is right, you can only traverse object not arrays for column bindings.

@spring's approach may work, but you would have to be careful as filters and sorting would only see the array not the data.

A better approach would probably to use ***mutators***, which would then make the data accessible to filters and sorters. so we can take @springs code and with a couple of tweaks make it work:

```js
//define mutator
function customMutator(value, data, type, params) {
   return data[params.field][params.index];
}

//assign mutator to columns
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    columns:[
    {title:"A", field:"trade_symbol"},
    {title:"B-1", field:"b1", 
    mutatorParams: {index:0, field:"technical_sum_List"},
    mutator: customMutator},

     {title:"B-2", field:"b2", 
    mutatorParams: {index:1, field:"technical_sum_List"},
    mutator: customMutator},

     {title:"B-3", field:"b3", 
    mutatorParams: {index:2, field:"technical_sum_List"},
    mutator: customMutator},

    ],
});
```

This approach has several benefits, it means columns can be sorted and filtered and included in downloads.

It also means that now each column has its own unique field, so can be more easily looked-up from outside the table.

in summary ***formatters*** are visual only and DO NOT affect sorting and filtering. ***mutators*** on the other hand update the underlying data and DO affect sorting, filtering and everything else.

More details of this can be found in the [Mutator Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/mutators)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

I found best answer:
We must use  `formatter: customFormatter`

```
        function customFormatter(cell, params) {
           return cell.getValue()[params.myid].rvalue;
        }
        
        
        for(var r=0;r<alldata[0].result.length;r++){
            table.addColumn({title:alldata[0].result[r].alias_title ,field:"result", formatterParams: {myid:r}, formatter: customFormatter});
        }
```